# How can i slide a div content in a particular angle using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am trying to slide a div content to top right side. i am trying but i can't get it, here is my html code

```
<html><body>  
<button id="animatenow">animate now!</button>   
<div id="container">
<div>hi</div>  
<div>there</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

here is script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#animatenow').click(function(){  $('#container').animate({width: "-=300px",marginTop: "-=1250px", height: "+=50px"},1500);});  });`
```

my css is

```
 #container{width:600px;color:#fff;background:#f00;height:400px}
```

my jsfiddle [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/W8Y4d/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a somewhat overly-complex means to do this:

```
$('#animatenow').click(function(){
    var that = $('#container');
    var h = that.height();
    var w = that.width();
    $('#container')
        .wrap('<div id="placeholder"></div>')
        .parent()
        .css({
            'width' : w,
            'height' : h
        })
        .find('#container')
        .css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'top' : 0,
            'left' : 0,
            'right' : 0,
            'bottom' : 0
        })
        .animate(
            {
                'top' : '-' + h,
                'left' : w,
                'right' : '-' + w,
                'bottom' : h
            },2000,
            function(){
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8Y4d/12/).

The above assumes you want to avoid the sliding element's text wrapping and re-flowing as it slides out of view. If you're okay with re-flowing text, then it's a lot easier and avoids adding a new wrapping element and the (hideous) call to `animate()`.

References:

- [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
- [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).
- [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: awesome this is to good, you given answer for exactly what i want, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you forgot `position:absolute` on the `#container` css

Comment: i updated my jsfiddle code link just check that, In that you can see what i am trying to  do

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#animatenow').click(function(){
    $('#container').animate({
         marginLeft: "700px",
         marginTop: "-=1250px",
    }
    ,1500);
    });
});
```

Are you trying to get an effect like this? I am unsure of what you mean, hope this helps a little.

Comment: I editted your jsFiddle a little. Goes top Right for me. http://jsfiddle.net/W8Y4d/4/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W8Y4d/5/) .Basicall you need to animate the left ,top and width properties after seting the position:absolute property to #container

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#animatenow').click(function() {
        $('#container').animate({
            right: '0',
            top: '0',
            width: '120',
            height: '120'
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

If you want to move the div out of visible area or hide it make the width and height 0px